# ImportError: cannot import name corpora with Gensim

Tags: python-2.7, nltk, lda, gensim

I have installed Anacoda Python v2.7 and Gensim v 0.13.0

I am using Spyder as IDE

I have the following simple code:

```
 from gensim import corpora
```

---

I got the following error:

```
from gensim import corpora

  File "gensim.py", line 7, in <module>

ImportError: cannot import name corpora
```

I reinstalled:
- Gensim
- Scipy
- Numpy
but still have the same issue.

Comment: Please make sure that you have Numpy>=1.3, Scipy>=0.7. Also there exists an issue with Anaconda while installing numpy.

Comment: Was your problem resolved?

Answer (score 17):

I had the same problem, when I named my own script "gensim.py". It was trying to load the modules from itself when importing from gensym.

So, avoid using "gensim.py" as a name of your script.

Comment: derp, totally did this

Answer (score 1):

You might want to refer to this [issue](https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/issues/198). Apparently, Anaconda behaves weirdly: bundling a different version of Numpy at runtime or something. I recommend using `pip` to install Gensim. Or `easy_install` Here's a [link](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/install.html) to help you install it properly.

Comment: I do no't  know how to solve it, it is really a bad problem

Answer (score 0):

My issue got resolved by uninstalling then reinstalling gensim using pip
then upgrading it

```
pip uninstall gensim
pip install gensim
pip install --upgrade gensim
```